# How to perform math operations between two tables

Tags: sql

I'm running two SQL queries that return to me a table with 3 rows each, I need to perform a math operator to subtract each row from both tables.

This is the first query, which returns 3 rows with x value, like

[image: returned table]

```sql
SELECT COUNT (*) AS MES 
FROM WorkOrder
WHERE asset LIKE '%DC1%'
AND YEAR (workOrderDate) BETWEEN 2018/11/01 AND 2018/11/31
OR businessUnit ='MM'
OR workType = '07'
OR workType = '08'
OR workType = '09'
OR workType = '10'
OR workType = '01'

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT (*) AS MES 
FROM WorkOrder
WHERE asset LIKE '%DC2%'
AND YEAR (workOrderDate) BETWEEN 2018/11/01 AND 2018/11/31
OR businessUnit ='MM'
OR workType = '07'
OR workType = '08'
OR workType = '09'
OR workType = '10'
OR workType = '01'

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT (*) AS MES 
FROM WorkOrder
WHERE asset NOT LIKE '%DC1%' AND asset NOT LIKE '%DC2%'
AND YEAR (workOrderDate) BETWEEN 2018/11/01 AND 2018/11/31
OR businessUnit ='MM'
OR workType = '07'
OR workType = '08'
OR workType = '09'
OR workType = '10'
OR workType = '01
```

and this is the second query which returns the same thing with other values

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS MES
FROM WorkOrder
WHERE asset LIKE '%DC1%' 
AND YEAR(workOrderDate) BETWEEN 2018/11/01 AND 2018/11/31
OR businessUnit ='MM'
OR workType = '07'
OR workType = '08'
OR workType = '09'
OR workType = '10'
OR workType = '01'
AND businessUnit ='MM'

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(*) AS MES
FROM WorkOrder
WHERE asset  LIKE '%DC2%' 
AND YEAR(workOrderDate) BETWEEN 2018/11/01 AND 2018/11/31
OR businessUnit ='MM'
OR workType = '07'
OR workType = '08'
OR workType = '09'
OR workType = '10'
OR workType = '01'
AND businessUnit ='MM'

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(*) AS MES
FROM WorkOrder
WHERE asset NOT LIKE '%DC1%' AND asset NOT LIKE '%DC2%'
AND YEAR(workOrderDate) BETWEEN 2018/11/01 AND 2018/11/31
OR businessUnit ='MM'
OR workType = '07'
OR workType = '08'
OR workType = '09'
OR workType = '10'
OR workType = '01'
AND businessUnit ='MM'
```

I need to perform an operation to subtract the values from each query, like

[image: operation wanted]

is there a method in SQL to do this? I could only find operators trough same table, can't figure out how to perform this.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you can simplify your `WHERE` clause a bit like this : `OR workType IN ('07', '08', '09', '10', '01')`

Comment: Are the rows always ordered in ascending order ? What dbms are you using ?

Comment: Your query logic is wrong. `... OR workType = '10' OR workType = '01' AND businessUnit ='MM'` is -> `... OR workType = '10' OR (workType = '01' AND businessUnit ='MM')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

provide a row_number to each table like so.

```
select t1.*, t2.b, t1.mes - t2.mes from
(select *,row_number() over (order by mes) a from table1)t1 join
(select *,row_number() over (order by mes) b from table2)t2 on t1.a = t2.b
```

Comment: In this case, t1 and t2 would be the result of a union of 3 queries each, so it's not a 'new table' in the database, how can I store it in a local variable so I can call the `-` operator?

Comment: you can store them as temp tables, as "select * into #temp1 from (UNION's)", and do the same for the second set of union's and then work the rest with the solution above.

Comment: how can I pass the resulted table from the query1 unions into (UNIONS)?

Comment: just wrap it around a parenthesis. like select * from (union 1 union 2) tUnions